# How to get data from an TypeScript Object?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic-framework

Block of code in modal:

```
export class Profile {
    constructor(public id : number,public name : string, public age: number,public address:any)
}
```

Block of code in TypeScript file:

```
profile : Profile[]= [new Profile(1,'hello',4,'address'),new Profile(1,'hello',4,'address'),
    new Profile(1,'hello',4,'address'),new Profile(1,'hello',4,'address')
  ];
```

How to get name id age as a list and navigate through JSON  object array, because following block of code is not displaying anything as it is an array of objects in JSON:

```
<div *ngFor="let p of profile">
    <ion-button>{{p.id}}</ion-button>
</div>
```

Comment: Your data is clearly not in json. Since you're using a class with instances it cannot be json because class instances are not serializable. It is of course possible in angular to iterate over array of instances and display their data, so please provide more information.

Comment: ok i shall reframe the question.Can you tell me how to display the data in html page

Comment: so far from what you posted in your question it seems to be okay that it should work. If you could please create a stackblitz where it doesn't work I could have a look and spot an issue. Although is there a specific reason you're using a class here instead of interface and object notation? Using classes for data models is a bad practice.

Comment: thanks @IndexOutOfDevelopersException for editting my question

Comment: @midhunsivarajan you are welcome! If you would like to get help I recommend to follow the guidelines: https://www.wikihow.com/Ask-a-Question-on-Stack-Overflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this particular problem, it is better to use `interface` :

```
interface Profile {
id : number;
name : string; 
age: number;
address:any;
}
```

now use it like so :

```
let profile : Profile[] = [{id : 1 , name : "Shahab" , age : 23 , adress : "Some where"} , ...]
```

Now you can access it easily .

Comment: <div *ngFor="let p of profile">

   {{p.id}}
    </div>
Will this work for the above solution.Where to declare interface

Comment: instead of using Profile class export it as interface

Comment: thanks man it worked.Can you please give me one more help.How to filter this data for a particular id

Comment: You're welcome.
just try to use `filter` higher-order function and you can use like so ;

```
arr.filter(item => item.id === myId);
```

Comment: and please if you find it useful, please check my answer as correct answer